# Making objects in Android from regex

Tags: java, android, regex, object, beaver

I am writing an Android application which gets string to parse using regex. Let's say it gets

```
'Tis an example image of a beaver {[beaver.jpg]} having an afternoon tea.
```

And what I want to get is TextView with `'Tis an example image of a beaver`, ImageView `beaver.jpg` and an another TextView `having an afternoon tea.`.

How (if possible) is creating objects possible after reading such string and parsing with regex?

Comment: Will it always be [text][image][text] as in one image and two text blocks or will there be multiple images imbedded in the text?

Comment: None of above. I will use custom classes that will extend View and there will be no rule in how they are going to be arranged.

Comment: Will the image path always be enclosed inside a `{[ ]}`, and will it always be a `.jpg`?

Comment: Ok, will there be always one image and one or two text blocks? Or could there be n images and m text blocks? Also, have you looked at WebViews and asset loading? It may be easier than what you are attempting.

Comment: @drewmoore No, but there will be some (about 20) specific rules for each object to be created. Image here is an example.

Comment: @ChrisS There will be n images, m textviews, k AnotherTextViews, l AnotherAnotherTextViews and so on. I wanted to avoid using WebView but I will probably by forced to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom view class should have a constructor that takes three `String` parameters, one for the path of the image, one for text to be displayed before the image and one for the text to display afterwards.

```
class YourView { 
    public YourView(String imgPath, String beforeImg, String afterImg){ 
         //add TextView for text before image 
         //add ImageView for image 
         //add TextView for text after image 
    }
}
```

If your image will always be enclosed in a `{[ ]}`, the regex `(.+)\\{\\[(.+)\\]\\}(.+)` will capture everything before the `{[` in capturing group 0, everything between `{[` and `}]` (i.e. the image path) in group 1, and everything after `}]` in group 2.

If you use a Java `Matcher` You can then achieve your desired result like:

```
    String pre, path, post; 
    while (matcher.find()){ 
        pre = matcher.group(0);
        path = matcher.group(1);
        post = matcher.group(2); 
        YourView view = new YourView(path, pre, post); 
        //add view 
    }
```

Note that, if the image is at the end or beginning of the text, you'll simply be passing empty strings as the third/first parameters here, which will result in the creation of empty TextViews, which should be harmless (or you can do a check and not create one for empty strings).

That said, also note that above code is untested (but should give you the general idea), and that I'm a Java programmer with little experience in Android - so let me know if there's an Android-specific reason this wouldn't work

Comment: Thanks, but it will not be as simple as text/image/text, but more complex and not always the same. Sometimes just one text, and sometimes heading/boldtext/text/italic/heading/text. I did not want to use WebView but I think this will be the best way.